# How to indicate some items of a long list are hidden by the user?

Tags: interaction-design

When creating a new database, there are `system tables` that vary depending on which type of database and whether using a third party service or not. These `system tables` are often not used, and in some occasions can clutter the UI. So we're making a new feature so that users can hide any tables optionally.

The problem is how do we indicate that there's hidden tables all the time?

I tried to pop out an info card above the list only once, just to tell users where to navigate to the hidden tables. But I'm not really sure about this. I'm asked to show an indicator all the time.

Another idea is to add some text at the bottom of list. But users will need to scroll all the way if the database contains hundreds of tables.

[image: table list wireframes]

Comment: This forum works best when you post some visual mocks of the context, and your efforts so far. It's helpful to see what the user will see, and the community can contribute a more useful answer for you.

Comment: @MikeM Thanks for telling me! I've added the wireframes for more context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try making a small indicator, but be explicit about how many are hidden. And rather than a banner explaining how to navigate to another section, bake some interaction into the tooltip, allowing them to click to go to the Setting area.

I'm not sure about some of the details of your use case, but this allows users to manage the hidden tables w/o getting in the way but still visible as to the count and status

[image]